# Буквы "И" и "Й" в сортировке Windows - баг или не баг?

Tags: winapi, кириллица, сортировка

Обнаружил, что CompareString (что ansi, что unicode) упорядочивает, содержащие И или Й, своеобразно. При этом наблюдать это можно просто в проводнике, создав файлы и отсортировать их. Пример: "Йемен" ложится раньше "Иордании", при этом "мои" раньше "мой" (но если "Иорданию" поменять на "Иарданию" она прыгает до). Пытался вспомнить, есть ли какие-то особые правила упорядочивания слов с этими двумя буквами и не смог вспомнить (а также найти в сети). Мои ожидания, что "й" должна быть после "и" всегда, здесь же что-то непонятное.

Баг или не баг?

Comment: И у меня глючит, только по другому (по крайней мере в cp1251 (она жа ANSI))


    c:/Users/avp $ cat tt.txt
    йцукен
    ицукен
    фбба
    аббб
    c:/Users/avp $ sort tt.txt
    фбба
    аббб
    ицукен
    йцукен
    c:/Users/avp $ c:/UnixUtils/usr/local/wbin/sort.exe tt.txt 
    аббб
    ицукен
    йцукен
    фбба
    c:/Users/avp $ 
    
Не удивляйтесь, это 7-я винда, просто команды из UnixUtils в emacs eshell.

Билл Гейтс..., что же от него еще ждать.

(сейчаc попробую простой программкой через strcmp() отсортировать).

Comment: Ну, это я по позднему времени лажанулся. Попробовал, qsort() с strcmp() сортирует также, как и UnixUtils. 

Присмотрелся - все верно, ведь **ф** и в самом деле должна быть последней.

--

Так что переходите в \*nix (или переносите их софт в винду).

Comment: @avp, понятно, лишнее подтверждение пока. Будем думать

Comment: Проверил в XP, там такого нет, так что это похоже баг более поздних версий Windows

Answer (score 4):

Насколько я понимаю, в сортировке используется «принцип кроссворда»: буквы И и Й считаются *одной и той же буквой* (если только слова не полностью одинаковы).

Пример сортировки в «Проводнике» на Windows 7:

[image]

[Документация](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317759.aspx) сообщает:

> ... two strings that are distinct in their binary representation can be linguistically equivalent

Попробуйте перевести строки в Unicode (в любом случае, однобайтные строки — зло, так что я бы вообще отказался от них, особенно в случае, если вы работаете с локализациями) и сравнивать в [`LOCALE_INVARIANT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373795.aspx).

Comment: @VladD, ссылка на Unicode вроде бы отсылает к тому, что Вы подозреваете, что в Unicode это решено более правильно, я правильно понял? Но те тесты, которые я делал для CompareStringW тоже проводил, тот же результат, к тому же проводник уже давно насколько я понимаю уникодный. Я готов смириться, если где-то указано, что "принцип кроссворда" правильный и принятый кем-то и где-то, а не то, что это какая-то случайность. В любом случае, спасибо за подробный ответ

Comment: @maksee: У функции `CompareString` есть флаги, вы пробовали `LOCAL_INVARIANT`? Unicode нужен, например, для того, чтобы вы смогли сравнивать без учёта языковых особенностей.

Comment: В [таблице Unicode](http://www.tamasoft.co.jp/en/general-info/unicode.html) коды `И`,`Й` 0x418, 0x419 и `и`,`й` 0x438, 0x439.

Так что, сортировка, где Йемен раньше Иокагамы явно не по кодам Unicode.

Почему-то в M$ решили, что в русском языке к `й` c `и` надо относиться также, как к буквам с тильдами (и пр. умляутами) в западноевропейских языках.

Comment: @avp: Угу. Локализация всегда была больным местом [во всём программировании](http://hashcode.ru/questions/262817#262848). С локализацией на европейские языки Microsoft в основном справилась, японский тоже со скрипом одолели ибо много клиентов, а вот остальные пока не очень как-то. Ну да ладно, ещё лет через 15, может, одолеют.

Comment: @avp, я откомментировал к основному тексту, но на всякий случай продублирую - в XP все в порядке, похоже баг появился позже видимо в процессе каких-то переделок